# Python threading ValueError

Tags: python, multithreading, valueerror

I am doing multithreading in Python and the code snippet is as below:

```
threads = [threading.Thread(target=process_data, args=(col_name)) for index, col_name in enumerate(df.dtypes)]
for t in threads:
    t.start()
for t in threads:
    t.join()

def process_data(column_name):
    max_value_df = spark.sql('SELECT MAX({column_name}) AS {column_name} FROM table'.format(column_name = column_name))
    time.sleep(1)
    max_value = max_value_df.first()[column_name]
```

The code is basically getting the maximum value of all the columns in a table. So, I am using threads to get every column's maximum value. So, consider my table has 5 columns: a,b,c,d,e so each thread will process one of the columns. The issue is that for some columns I get the error: `ValueError: 'a' is not in list` showing that the `max_value_df` does not have that particular column name in its result. This behavior is pretty random. Sometimes I get no error at all and at time it is for any of the five columns. Please suggest what is the problem here and how can I solve it. I have tried adding `time.sleep(1)` so that I can wait before the thread returns a result, but the issue is still there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think ValueError is raised when max_value_df.first() is a list, you can check this type to find why and when max_value_df.first() return list

Comment: That particular key (which is the column name) is not found in that list. Which I think is because the result comes from any other column's thread and hence the column name is different.

Comment: df is a local variable, cannot get value from other thread.

Comment: So why is it that sometimes it gets the value from df but sometimes return the error? Shouldn't the result be same everytime?

Comment: I think the max_value_df.first() should return dict not a list, column_name is a string not a integer. print max_value_df.first() to check the result type is the correct type.

Comment: As it is a spark data frame, max_value_df.first() has type pyspark.sql.types.Row. And doing max_value_df.first()[column_name] does return correct result. Its just that it fails some time but works fine otherwise.